# Pushing the result of a counter onto an array for each for loop iteration

Tags: arrays, loops, pine-script

This is getting closer thanks also to mr_statler.

```
//@version=5
indicator("sma coun", overlay=false)

myArray = array.new_float(0)
var int counter = 0

for i = 200 to 201
    if close > ta.sma(close, i)
        counter := counter +1
    array.push(myArray, counter)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,5, str.tostring(array.join(myArray, " - ")))
    label.new(bar_index, 2, "array size: " + str.tostring(array.size(myArray)))
```

The above code gives as a result the following:

[image]

Array size is correct, because we are iterating 200 to 201. However the results above are not.
It should be [image] and [image]
but instead is summing both numbers together. What can we do to have the following result?
[image]

Comment: "... but is not working" doesn't provide enough context to help. What do you expect from the script, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Olaf, I'm expecting like a counter counting how many times a price bar closes above the sma, and store that value into the array, for every single i (from 1 to 200)

Comment: Yes, you already stated that in the question. But you also said, it doesn't work. So, what is the script doing instead?

Comment: On Stack Overflow we have a preference for useful and informative titles. I have tried to improve it from "Loop and arrays madness" to something more specific, but I don't understand financial terms. Feel free to improve it further.

Comment: The script is not saving the "counter" values into an array, the array value is always 0 for some reason

Comment: Using `ta.sma(close, i)` in a for loop does not really make any sense and should give you a warning. What is your purpose of using that statement in a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

The code just need 2 adjustments:

1. From what I understand from your question, you're looking to push the result of the `counter` variable to an array, but currently in your code you're pushing the result of the `counter` variable each time you add 1 to it. To fix that, you'll just need to calculate `counter` in the `for` loop, but adding the result of `counter` after the `for` loop finished.
2. If you want to save all of the `counter` results to one array, you'll need the array to "remember" all previous results. In Pinescript, all variables gets reset on each new bar, and that's why the array at `barstate.islast` will only include one item. If you want the array to not reset on each new bar, you just need to add the `var` keyword.

Here is the code after changing those things:

```
//@version=5
indicator("sma coun", overlay=false)

var myArray = array.new_float(0)
int counter = 0

for i = 1 to 200
    if close > ta.sma(close, i)
        counter := counter + 1

array.push(myArray, counter)

plot(counter)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, 0, array.join(myArray, ','))
```

Comment: Thank you mr_statler, it is very clear your explanation. How can we push each i change onto an array?